# My element is not filling the entire space of the page

Tags: html, css

So using the CSS code below I wanted to make my page fill entirely with an image located on my computer. Instead, it turned out like this:

```
#background {
    background-image: url("anFtp");
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
}
```

[image: The Stupid Image]

As you can probably see there is white space located on the top and left of the page. Now I have tried multiple things, this is just what my code looks like now. The original code looked like:

```
#background {
    background-image: url("anFtp");
    position: fixed;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 900px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

There are multiple results for this and I have tried them (changing `1600px` and `900px` to `100%`) but most of them tell me that something someone else wrote was incorrect, not an actual error of the code or the knowledge of the writer.

*EDIT / addition to below answer*

adding what the below answer suggested helped the problem but now it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Does it work

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

EDITED: For updated problem

```
#background {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It worked but now it has a bigger gap on the top. I will paste in an edit to my question.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Check my comment. does that work for your needs. Has it fixed the problem. Comment your current css for background and try that. Thats how i have it in my site. obv change the url of the image.

Comment: It centred it perfectly, yet there is still the large gap on the above. I'm going to remove some of my elements to see if that works.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Hmm. Try `top center` rather than `center center`

`#background {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: It's all good and fixed. Thanks for the help, your answer came closest so it has been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers come with a ***default style sheet***. It provides a basic set of CSS rules.

Here is a sample default style sheet from the W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html

As you can see from the sample, it is recommended that browsers include `body { margin: 8px }`. That's likely the source of the white space between the `body` and the viewport.

To override the default use `body { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could reproduce the problem with the bigger gap. Do you have a live demo or site?

Comment: No I  am working on this offline. Would a paste of my code ( two files , one css the other html ) in my question do?

Comment: The problem has been fixed, although It includes different answers to complete the full page. One problem was an extremely long <p> </p> and another was instead of body { margin: 0; } I did #background {
margin: -16px;
}

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem solved. Without posting all relevant code, there's no way we could have known about the paragraph problem or even the negative margin fix (which doesn't sound very efficient).

Comment: Thanks, even I could not have guessed it was due to the large paragraph. What html would I have had to include to fix the negative margin( for future use I don't wan't to be doing the same thing all over again)? Would I need to include the <body> the element ( <div> ) or what?

Comment: Again, with only a small section of your code posted, there's no way to provide more detailed feedback. But regardless, Stack Overflow is for solving code problems. If you want your code reviewed for quality and efficiency, use Stack's [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score -1):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```